# Implementing grouping in a custom WinRT ListCollectionView class

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am using the `ListCollectionView` class provided at the following link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So

However, it doesn't seem to support grouping the items.

I tried doing the following to group the items, but it would throw an error on the `.GroupBy` line:

```
ListCollectionView src;
src.Add(new Music("Michael Jackson", "Thriller", "Billie Jean"));
src.Add(new Music("Michael Jackson", "Dangerous", "She Drives Me Wild"));
src.Add(new Music("Eminem", "The Marshall Mathers LP 2", "The Monster"));
src.Add(new Music("Lupe Fiasco", "Lasers", "The Show Goes On"));
src.GroupBy((Music p) => p.Artist);
```

As last line, `src.GroupBy((Music p) => p.Artist);` throws an overload of arguments error.

Is it not possible to group the items?

Comment: From the article: "Note that ListCollectionView class does not implement grouping. That is a more advanced feature that will be left as an exercise for the reader."

Comment: Yes, hence I said, "However, it doesn't seem to support grouping the items." The question is about implementing the grouping.